# Suddenly no custom 2010 workflows works anymore - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, custom, custom-workflow

I've not access to the production environment so **I can't see the ULS log**.

I've got several 2010 workflows that worked pretty well yesterday. But today they suddenly stopped working. When I try to manually start a workflow I get "Sorry something went wrong" and "file not found".

So I thought it was some errors in my custom workflow. So I just added a new custom list and added a simple 2010 workflow, that add a extra element in the list. -> published.
When I look in the library workflow, I can see the workflow. But then I try to start the workflow it fails "file not found". When I try to modify the view to see the workflow column it does not appear!

I've tried many different workflows without any luck! Then I tried to add a OOTB workflow and it runs!

I'm in a SP2013 environment, and I've tried:

- Restarting the workflow feature
- Tried to add a simple workflow in another site collection, fails

Comment: Check the ULS logs for complete error trace, try to restart workflow timer jobs, restart the SharePoint Timer services.....is it publishing site?

Comment: Yes, it's a publishing site. Witch SharePoint timer services should I restart? (Central admin?)

Comment: You have to make sure "Workflow" timer jobs run successfully. If you dont have CA/ server access then it will be tough to identify issue...

Answer (score 0):

System administrator run

Disable-SPFeature -Identity WorkflowServiceStore -Url http://superawesome.info -Force

Then you have to reenable the feature again. And a IIS reset

That worked :)